# using css to control size and colour of an svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I painstakingly created a search icon and exported it as an svg. This now appears on the header of a website but I am trying to have css control of the size and colour of it so I can size the icon responsively, match the colour of text on the site, and also have some kind of rollover colour change or lightening/darkening when users roll over the icon.
I don't want to use inline svg but I am happy to use either the img-src or object techniques below.

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.onSearchClick} title="Search site">
<img src="//example-image-server/i/search_classic.svg" height="20" alt="Search the site"/>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="//example-image-server/i/search_classic.svg" height="20" className="search-classic">Your browser does not support SVGs</object>
<span>Search</span>
```

Without using javascript, how do I control both colour and size.

I  have tried creating a css class "search-classic" and setting fill: value but it has no effect.

Please note this code is for React, so uses className="search-classic" instead of just class="search-classic"

Comment: It would be helpful to see the SVG code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just quote what is the result of 2 google searches. Please do your own research before asking questions.

> #### Using SVG as an `<object>`
>
> […] You can link to an SVG file and retain the ability to affect its parts with CSS by using `<object>`.
>   […] But, if you want the CSS stuff to work, you can't use an external stylesheet or `<style>` on the document, you need to use a `<style>` element inside the SVG file itself.

```
<svg ...>
  <style>
    /* SVG specific fancy CSS styling here */
  </style>
  ...
</svg>
```

> […] SVG has a way to declare an external stylesheet, which can be nice for authoring and caching and whatnot. This only works with `<object>` embedding of SVG files as far as I've tested. You'll need to put this in the SVG file above the opening `<svg>`

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>
```

Source: ["Using SVG" — CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-11)

#### Appendix 1

I looked at the codepen project you provided in the comments. Let's take the following file and fix it:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="136" height="136" viewBox="0 0 136 136">
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      <![CDATA[
      g {
          fill: yellow;
          stroke: black;
          stroke-width: 1;
          transition: fill 1s linear 0s;
      }
      g:hover {
          fill: blue;
      }
      ]]>
  </style>
  <path d="M121…Z"/>
</svg>
```

You are trying to style `g`, which is an SVG group. A group could contain multiple paths, circles, squares, etc. Unfortunately, you don't have any group in this SVG icon. You only have a `path`.

Additionally, to enable the `:hover` selector, you would have to enable `pointer-events` on the elements. [This document should provide more information on that.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events)

All in all, here is a working example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="136" height="136" viewBox="0 0 136 136">
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      <![CDATA[
      path { /* TARGET THE CORRECT ELEMENT */
          fill: yellow;
          stroke: black;
          stroke-width: 1;
          transition: fill 1s linear 0s;
          pointer-events: all; /* ENABLE POINTER EVENTS */
      }
      path:hover { /* TARGET THE CORRECT ELEMENT */
          fill: blue;
      }
      ]]>
  </style>
  <path d="M121…Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I had Googled and read that source before asking the question so have tried that already. Sadly, neither of those two options seem to work. I simply cannot change the fill colour of the svg using a stylesheet it seems.

Comment: Then it might have to do with the actual CSS that you wrote? Please show exactly how you tried to change the fill color.

Comment: @Tech75 did you read my comment? I forgot to mention your username…

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can’t show the current code because it’s got some sensitive data on it so will clean it out with dummy data and then share with you.

Comment: Ok. So, using a Codepen template I was able to recreate it. You can see how my css style in /includes/_variables.scss has the .search-classic class, and background-color is being picked up but fill colour is not. You will see two different search svgs. One uses style inside the svg and one uses a tag at the beginning. Both of these approaches were recommended in the article but neither seem to work. Hoping this is something obvious on my side. https://codepen.io/Sparkomatic/project/editor/DepvRV

Comment: @Tech75 Did you have the time to read the additions I made to my answer? Has that helped you or even fully solved your problem?

Comment: Thanks Barthy for your help. That has indeed been helpful.

Comment: @Tech75 Glad I could help! Always remember to mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

The author of the question writes:

> I don't want to use inline svg but I am happy to use either the
>   img-src or object techniques below.   I have tried creating a css
>   class "search-classic" and setting fill: value but it has no effect.

### Let me offer you an action plan:

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the styles of the icon from the external style sheet.

- **Modifying the SVG file icon**

  1. Add in the first line of your SVG icon file an indication of which style sheet will be used:

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>`

This should be exactly the first line, otherwise problems may arise.

2. Wrap your svg code with `<symbol>` tags and assign it a unique identifier.

   3. *Remove all styles of svg elements, since they have higher priorities than the styles of external tables `CSS`*

```html
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>
<svg  version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
<symbol id="searchIcon" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
  <path id="myPath" d="M35,40H11v-0.051C5.947,39.447,2,35.186.... z"/>
</symbol> 
   </svg>
```

- **Adding an SVG file to HTML**

Suppose you assign the edited file the name `sprite.svg`
In your case, adding to HTML is done only through the tag `<object>`
*This command should be located higher in HTML than the command to call the icons from the sprite.*

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg">
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

- **Calling an icon from the sprite**

`<svg  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <use xlink:href="sprite.svg#searchIcon"></use>
</svg>`

- **Adding rules for forced inheritance to an external table `CSS`**

Once you use the `<use>` command, your SVG falls into the shadow DOM and you need to add the following `CSS`

see [the article by Sara Soueidan](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) in the section "Styling  Content with the CSS all Property"

```
path#myPath {
    fill: inherit;
    stroke: inherit;
    stroke-width: inherit;
    transform: inherit;
    /* ... */
}
```

Pain is universal, tested in practice

```
svg path {
    fill: inherit;
    stroke: inherit;
    stroke-width: inherit;
    transform: inherit;
    /* ... */
}
```

After all the items in the plan have been executed, the icon will obediently accept the styles from the external table `CSS`.